# How do I fix SQL Server Database Project Ambiguous References?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am having trouble getting Visual Studio 2022 (and 2017) to work with a simple Database Project.  I have extracted a data tier application and stored it as a .dacpac file.  I have added it as a database reference (Same server, different database.)

It is happy with this and can build and deploy it:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View1]
AS SELECT * FROM [$(CBS_ODS)].dbo.rm_acct
```

But this gives errors:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View1]
AS SELECT _IsCurrent FROM [$(CBS_ODS)].dbo.rm_acct
```

Specifically the two errors:

> SQL71561: Computed Column: [dbo].[View1].[_IsCurrent] has an unresolved reference to object [$(CBS_ODS)].[dbo].[rm_acct].[_IsCurrent]
> SQL71561: View: [dbo].[View1] has an unresolved reference to object [$(CBS_ODS)].[dbo].[rm_acct].[_IsCurrent]

At this point I've come to the conclusion that Database Projects are unusably buggy.  Is there (a) any solution to this or (b) any way to turn of parsing/inspection entirely?  It seems like the database references can see views, but not the columns in the views?

Comment: I should point out that all these SQL queries work just fine of course if you run them in Management Studio.  The _IsCurrent column exists in the rm_acct table.  I extracted the data tier application from the exact database I'm referring to when deploying.

Comment: For the second issue, I suggest you 1. Give the view a different name; 2. Alias your two tables and refer to them seperately in the select `SELECT T1.*, T2.*`

Comment: Doesn't help.  It will just report that the new View name already exists - even though clearly it doesn't.  Aliasing the tables (which is completely optional in SQL) also makes no difference.

Comment: With regards to the cross join, it just doesn't like that you have two sets of the same column names. In fact if you try to create a view like that in SSMS you get "The column xyz was specified multiple times for View1" which is basically what VS is telling you. So there is a reason for the cross join case, and there is also a solution - alias column names so that they are unique. I suggest you focus on the first case which is the real problem here

Comment: OK, I was just trying to show that the introduction of any join causes failure too.  Let's just remove that example.

Comment: Database projects are much pickier and don't support a lot of stuff. I typically work directly with the project, not a dacpac. I also typically never do any cross database stuff and so far so good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243506/discussion-between-chris-kl-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the solution.  Basically you need to add the database you're referring to as a reference, as well as all databases that reference refers to!  ie. transitive references aren't automatic.

Pretty annoying as it means that the database reference isn't properly encapsulated from the user's point of view.